# Changing parameters in a 3x3 Matrix trying to find the general solution.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Consider the system
$$X^{'}= \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&a \\ 0&b&0\\ a&0&0 \end{pmatrix}X$$

depending on the two parameters a and b.

1) find the general solution of this system.
\begin{pmatrix} -\lambda&0&a \\ 0&(b-\lambda)&0\\ a&0&-\lambda \end{pmatrix}
$-\lambda(b-\lambda) (-\lambda)+ a(b-\lambda) (-\lambda) = -\lambda^{3} +(b+a) \lambda^{2}-ab\lambda $

$(\lambda^{2} -(b+a) \lambda+ab) (-\lambda)$

$(\lambda -[(b+a)/2])^{2} = -ab + [(a+b)^{2}/4]$

$\lambda_{1} =  (-ab + [(a+b)/4])^{1/2}$
$\lambda_{2} =  -(-ab + [(a+b)/4])^{1/2}$
$\lambda_{3} =  0$

im not sure how to force the eigenvalues out of this and subbing this mess into that equation for each eigenvalue  is there an easier way to compute this?

EDIT
as pointed out below this is a mess by expanding down the second column of the matrix 
we have
$\lambda_{1} =  b$
$\lambda_{2} =  -a$
$\lambda_{3} =  a$

Where
$V_{1}=<0,1,0>$
$V_{2}=<1,0,(-1)>$
$V_{3}=<1,0,(1)>$

Why isnt this the general solution?

$C_{1} e^{bt} V_{1}$ + $C_{2} e^{-at} V_{2}$ + $C_{3} e^{at} V_{3}$

2) sketch the region in the ab plane where this system has different types of phase portraits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at that matrix right, its determinant is obviously $(b-\lambda)(\lambda^2-a^2)$, which should make it a breeze to find eigenvalues and eigenvectors.

Comment: im not sure how you got that but, that would mean $\lambda$ = b,a,-a

Edit nvm im a moron

Comment: Evaluate the determinant by expansion along the second row.

Answer (score 2):

---

$X^{'}= \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&a \\ 0&b&0\\ a&0&0 \end{pmatrix}X$    , $X=\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$$\begin{pmatrix} x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix} =\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&a \\ 0&b&0\\ a&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$$then we have 
 $$\begin{cases}
x'=az  & \text{} \\
 y'=by& \text{}  \\
z'=ax & \text{}  \\
\end{cases}$$
  w
e have $y=e^{bt+d_1}$$$x'=az\to x''=az'\to x''=a^2x$$ easily find x then by substitution find z

Comment: sorry i don't really understand how u got all those things.
or in general what that even says, perhaps its time for me to go to sleep...

Comment: @julien, $z'=ax$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, sure, I added a typo to a typo...Thanks.

Comment: Nice observation, Maisam. So doing this, we find necessary conditions on $x,y,z$. And we need to check that they work afterwards. +1.

Comment: i follow the train of logic to get to $x^{''}=a^{2}x$

Comment: @Faust7:use characteristics polynomial to solve it $(D^2-a^2)x=0$

Comment: Sorry i have never seen anything like this before i am not sure why your trying to find x?

Comment: are you talking about the vectors?

Comment: @Faust7:i offer look on this book differential equation and dynamical system an introduction to chaos of Morris sorry i dont have time to explain  i must go university

Comment: haha, you have been more then helpful sir thank you very much for all your help!